# MySQL how to LIKE match a parameter + wildcard?

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I have an old song database that I wanted to transfer to a new one.
My old database looks like this, multiple values are stuffed together in a field separated by comma

```
SONG
id    |    title    |    artist    |    lyricist
1           abc     |     John     |    John, Mary
```

In the new tables I have them separated and connected through ids.  I already had all the artist names copied to the new 'artist' table.

```
ARTIST
ID    |    NAME
1     |    John
2     |    Mary
```

I'm now trying to copy the lyricist column to the new 'song_lyricist' table,

```
SONG lYRICIST
SONG_ID    |    ARTIST_ID
1               1
1          |    2
```

this is my sql select query

```
SELECT song.id, song.lyricist, artist.id
FROM song
JOIN artist
ON
song.lyricist LIKE artist.name
```

The query works on selecting fields that have a single value, but doesn't work on the one with multiple values with the comma. I have tried to combine it with the wildcard "song.lyricist LIKE artist.name + '%'" but it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: ON (song.lyricist LIKE artist.name OR *another conditon* )

Comment: what can be the other conditions? Matching both column value + wildcard is the only condition I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT song.id, song.lyricist, artist.id
FROM song
JOIN artist
ON
song.lyricist LIKE '%',

**You can use this or Go for Store Procure for this kind of approach**
refer this link--
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/161/creating-a-simple-stored-procedure/

Comment: this is going to match everything